# How to convert touch coordinates into local object coordinates in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, transformation

I want to transform point coordinates received on user touch down to local object coordinates.

On touch down I get (x,y) in screen coordinates:

```
left-top=(0,0), bottom-right=(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT).
```

Then i do `camera.unproject(..)` and get (x,y) in world coordinate (ViewPort), but I don't get how to transform the aquired point to a local object coordinate. I have tried some operations (see comments in `MyRect.unproject(..)`) but none of them work.

```
public class MyLibgdxGame extends Game implements InputProcessor {
    private MyRect obj;
    ...
    public void render() {
        camera.update();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.1f,.1f,.1f,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        renderer.line(0,0, 0, 30);
        renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.line(0,0, 30, 0);
        renderer.end();

        obj.render(renderer);
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        float units = 100f;
        float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(units * aspectRatio, units);
        camera.update();
    }

    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Gdx.app.log("my", String.format("[Touch] x: %d, y: %d", screenX, screenY));
        Vector3 v = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
        camera.unproject(v);
        Gdx.app.log("my", String.format("[S to VP] x: %.1f, y: %.1f", v.x, v.y));

        // !! convert world coordinate "v" to local object coordinate
        obj.unproject(v);
        Gdx.app.log("my", String.format("[VP to Object] x: %.1f, y: %.1f", v.x, v.y));

        return false;
    }
    ...
}

public class MyRect {

    private Rectangle rect;
    private float angle;
    private Matrix4 transform;

    public MyRect(float x, float y, float w, float h, float angle) {
        this.rect = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
        this.angle = angle;

        transform = new Matrix4().translate(x,y,0).rotate(0,0,1,angle);
    }

    public void render(ShapeRenderer renderer) {

        renderer.identity();
        renderer.setTransformMatrix(transform);

        renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Rectangle);
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.rect(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
        renderer.end();

        r.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        r.line(0,0, 0, 30);
        r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        r.line(0,0, 30, 0);
        r.end();

        renderer.identity();
    }

    public Vector3 unproject(Vector3 v) {
//      return v.mul(transform); // 1
//      return v.prj(transform); // 2
        return v.rotate(0,0,1,angle).sub(new Vector3(rect.x, rect.y, 0)); //3
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it all wrong.

```
camera.unproject(v);
Gdx.app.log("my", String.format("[S to VP] x: %.1f, y: %.1f", v.x, v.y));

// !! convert world coordinate "v" to local object coordinate
obj.unproject(v);
Gdx.app.log("my", String.format("[VP to Object] x: %.1f, y: %.1f", v.x, v.y));
```

The "local coordinates" that you talk about are camera coordinates. When you unproject your touch, you convert your Screen coordinates to Camera coordinates. But what you want are World Coordinates. No need to unproject your object as that will give you an useless vector. Just convert your Camera coordinates to World coordinates and use those:

```
camera.unproject(v);
Gdx.app.log("my", String.format("[S to VP] x: %.1f, y: %.1f", v.x, v.y));
x = camera.position.x-camera.viewportWidth+v.x;
y = camera.position.y-camera.viewportHeight+v.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to have `MyRect` extend `Actor` and use `Actor.stageToLocalCoordinates()`. If you don't want to subclass `Actor`, get the libgdx source and take a look at the aforementioned method.

[Actor (libgdx API)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#stageToLocalCoordinates%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2%29)